# Is there a good way to instantiate temporary tables with Postgres?

Tags: pandas, postgresql, grafana

I would like to save CSV strings in a Postgres table, then turn them into temporary tables for use in Grafana and everywhere else SQL is used when needed.

We are starting to extricate ourselves from both Pandas and our semi-proprietary storage system, where our Pandas dataframes are stored.  There is no richness (no metadata) and no reach (not usable outside of Python).

Pandas dataframes can be thought of as two-dimensional matrices and/or miniature SQL tables.  We have upwards of 100,000 such dataframes saved, and nearly all are "timeseries", meaning the index column are dates.

One very attractive product which we have started to use is Grafana, although apparently built for high-frequency log data and the like, is actually not at all bad with more traditional low frequency data, such as what you might expect with economic data, inflation, consumer price index, exchange rates, and so on.

On the Python / Pandas side, I write a copy of the CSV-like string to Postgres where fields are separated by tabs. I don't use the Pandas code as it potentially introduces "impurities" which could cause the import into Postgres to fail, instead this is simple Python code which reformats the dataframe into more Postgres-friendly text.

As Grafana supports Postgres, I've been experimenting with the following code:  (note this is Grafana which allows only SQL statements, this should also work in PSQL, finally the comments would not work in real life)

```
// this is the CSV-like data I wrote from Python, a single CSV-like string, tabs
copy (select data from repository where series_name = 'rampant_inflation') 
    to '/home/grafana/temp/mytemp.txt'; 

// table to receive the CSV.  it has to match.
create temporary table mygraphs(date date, value double precision);

// load up the data 
copy mygraphs from '/home/grafana/temp/mytemp.txt';

// Postgres query which Grafana plots
select date as time, value from mygraphs order by time;
```

Generally this procedure fails at the third statement, copy mygraphs from ...., where it fails with different problems, depending on the format used.

Approaching this problem systematically, the CSV-like data string written to Postgres looks like this: (or at least the first few rows)

```
"2014-01-01"    0.0
"2014-02-01"    -2147483648
"2014-03-01"    -2147483648
"2014-04-01"    -2147483648
"2014-05-01"    -2147483648
"2014-06-01"    -2147483648
"2014-07-01"    -2147483648
"2014-08-01"    -2147483648
"2014-09-01"    -2147483648
"2014-10-01"    -2147483648
"2014-11-01"    -2147483648
"2014-12-01"    -2147483648
"2015-01-01"    -0.0423136399521442
"2015-02-01"    -0.0378199225444889
"2015-03-01"    -0.0379994483243077
"2015-04-01"    -0.0450069482605961
"2015-05-01"    -0.0473967757668197
```

no missing values, '\t' is the field delimiter, '\n' the line delimiter.

With no format qualifier, text is used, and the file which Postgres has written to my temporary file in the very first COPY command looks like this:

```
"2014-01-01"\t0.0\n"2014-02-01"\t-2147483648\n"2014-03-01"\t-2147483648\n"2014-04-01"\t-2147483648\n"2014-05-01"\t-2147483648\n"2014-06-01"\t-2147483648\n"2014-07-01"\t-2147483648\n"2014-08-01"\t-2147483648\n"2014-09-01"\t-2147483648\n...
```

Looks OK, tabs and new lines escaped, but fails in Postgres with

```
db query error: pq: invalid input syntax for type date: ""2014-01-01" 0.0 "2014-02-01" -2147483648 "2014-03-01" -2147483648 "2014-04-01" -2147483648 "2014-05-01" -2147483648 "2014-06-01" -2147483648 "2014-07-01" -2147483648 "2014-08-01" -2147483648 "2014-09-01" -2147483648 "2014-10-01" -2147483648 "2014-11-01" -2147483648 "2014-12-01" -2147483648 "2015-01-01" ...
```

Looks to me that it's treating the entire string as the first date field.

Now suppose I change to format 'csv', the temporary files looks like this:

```
"""2014-01-01"" 0.0
""2014-02-01""  -2147483648
""2014-03-01""  -2147483648
""2014-04-01""  -2147483648
""2014-05-01""  -2147483648
""2014-06-01""  -2147483648
""2014-07-01""  -2147483648
""2014-08-01""  -2147483648
...
""2022-07-01""  -0.0104285432988056
""2022-08-01""  0.003729020679859
""2022-09-01""  -0.0016335545143816
""2022-10-01""  -0.0068911686143867
""2022-11-01""  -0.0189265400298481
""2022-12-01""  -0.0162619917989639
""2023-01-01""  -0.0103153654467852"
```

and I get an identical error as I would with the first example 'text'.  Note that the first Postgres copy has doubled the quotes around the date, then added a single quote at the beginning then at the end of the string.

Lastly, suppose I want to live dangerously, and now use the (format CSV) for the first copy and use (format TEXT) in the second, it almost works.

Here Postgres gets to the last line and issues the following:

```
db query error: pq: invalid input syntax for type double precision: "-0.0103153654467852""
```

Looks to me that it does not like its own trailing quote.  Similarly, if I add a trailing new line, it fails processing the next field, a date.  (Is there an end-of-file marker or something??)

Thanks in advance for your help and suggestions.

Comment: Use the same `format` in both COPY commands.

Comment: tried that, format CSV, format text. seems text would work if delimiter would work

Comment: C style escapes are not standard SQL postgres does support them but you need to use E prefix `E'\t'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, I did the following:

```
// this is the CSV-like data I wrote from Python, a single CSV-like string, tabs
copy (select data from repository where series_name = 'rampant_inflation') 
    to '/home/grafana/temp/mytemp.txt' (format 'csv'); 

// table to receive the CSV.  it has to match.
create temporary table mygraphs(date date, value double precision);

// load up the data, but fix the data up a bit first, 
// get rid of extra quote and new line at end 
copy mygraphs from program 
    'truncate /home/grafana/temp/mytemp.txt -s -2; 
    cat /home/grafana/temp/mytemp.txt';

// Postgres query which Grafana plots
select date as time, value from mygraphs order by time;
```

In short, Postgres cannot round trip its own data, that is, output produced by the COPY command cannot be read back in.  This example is only slightly disturbing as COPY appears to tolerate the first extra quote but not the last extra quote.  The truncate command gets rid of the extra quote and new line at the end.

Comment: Also, the "copy mygraphs from program" paradigm opens up a lot of possibilities